# is it enough to set "shopt -s nocaseglob" once / script?

Tags: bash, shopt

Is it enough to set `shopt -s nocaseglob` once in a bash-script, or do I need to set it before every function in the script.

Do I need to turn it on again after the script is completed or is this only a temporary setting for just that terminal?

Comment: "need" is an interesting verb; there's an answer regarding the scope of shell options, but I can also imagine explicitly setting it (along with a comment) inside a function where I relied on its behavior.

Comment: `shopt` is non-portable. The main issue is to make sure it gets called only with a shell that suppotts it. I believe this is bash only.

Comment: updated the question, it's regarding bash

Comment: Once is enough. Note that your script will run in a separate bash process (unless you use `source`), so that shell option will not affect your current shell.